# Encog input layer size Error?

Tags: c#, .net, neural-network, encog

So I'm new to Encog and I followed Mr.Heaton's introduction to Encog in C# and tried my hand at it. My simple exercise was to develop a network that predicated the 'Insanity Level' of a person depending on their age and I provided a training set. However, I find myself facing this problem:

"The input layer size of 6 must match the training input size of 1."

I'm sure I'm doing a major mistake somewhere, here's my simple code.

```
public static double[][] InsanityInput = 
{
     //age
     new double[1]{20},
     new double[1]{25},
     new double[1]{30},
     new double[1]{35},
     new double[1]{40},
     new double[1]{45}
};   
public static double[][] InsanityIDEAL = 
{
     //insanity level
     new double[1]{100},
     new double[1]{90},
     new double[1]{75},
     new double[1]{60},
     new double[1]{30},
     new double[1]{20}
};

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     BasicNetwork network = new BasicNetwork();
     network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 6)); //input layer
     network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 6)); //hidden layer
     network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 1)); //output layer
     network.Structure.FinalizeStructure();
     network.Reset();
     INeuralDataSet trainingSet = new BasicNeuralDataSet(InsanityInput, InsanityIDEAL);
     ITrain train = new ResilientPropagation(network, trainingSet);

     int epoch = 1;
     do
     {
         train.Iteration();
         Console.WriteLine("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:" + train.Error);
         epoch++;
     } while((epoch<5000)&&(train.Error > 0.001));

     double[] inputArray = {27}; //input the age
     INeuralData inputData = new BasicNeuralData(inputArray);
     INeuralData outputData = network.Compute(inputData);
     Console.WriteLine("\nNetwork Prediction: " + outputData.ToString());

     Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

It's in fact the same code discussed in the tutorials by Mr.Heaton. Help me out please, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Short:**

Line

```
  network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 6)); //input layer
```

Should loke like this

```
  network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 1)); //input layer
```

**Why:**

You are building basic neural network and in fact [Single Layer Perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron). As an input you provide one value *age* and as an output you require one number which is *insanity level*. In your code you create network that expect 6 signals as input but you provided only one *age* and Encog doesn't know what signal should be on other 5 neurons.

Your network looks like this:

[image: Wrong graph]

I marked inputs without signal to red. Because you heave only one variable you need to reduce your input layer to 1.
 Another thing that is wrong in your code is lack of [normalization](http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Normalization). You get input in range (0-100) and expect output in range (0-100). [Sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) result set is form 0 to 1, so before training your network you need to normalize training set. Remember to normalize output when you will test your network. You can do it wiht [NormalizeArray](http://www.heatonresearch.com/javadoc/encog-3.0/org/encog/util/arrayutil/NormalizeArray.html)